# Workaround for case-sensitive input to dir

Tags: directory, octave, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am using Octave 5.1.0 on Windows 10 (x64). I am parsing a series of directories looking for an Excel spreadsheet in each directory with "logbook" in its filename. The problem is these files are created by hand and the filenaming isn't consistent: sometimes it's "LogBook", other times it's "logbook", etc...

It looks like the string passed as input to the `dir` function is case-sensitive so if I don't have the correct case, `dir` returns an empty struct. Currently, I am using the following workaround, but I wondered if there was a better way of doing this (for a start I haven't captured all possible upper/lower case combinations):

```
logbook = dir('*LogBook.xls*');
if isempty(logbook)
  logbook = dir('*logbook.xls*');
  if isempty(logbook)
    logbook = dir('*Logbook.xls*');
    if isempty(logbook)
      logbook = dir('*logBook.xls*');
      if isempty(logbook)
        error(['Could not find logbook spreadsheet in ' dir_name '.'])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: One approach would be to do `dir('*.xls*')` and then loop through the file names to find a case-insensitive match. Not any simpler than what you’re doing now, but probably prettier.

Comment: To add to what @CrisLuengo said, you can get the list using `dir('*.xls*')`, then use [`strcmpi`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html). An alternative would be [`regexpi`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexpi.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the list of filenames (either via `readdir`, `dir`, `ls`), and then search for the string in that list. If you use `readdir`, it can be done like this:

```
[files, err, msg] = readdir ('.'); # read current directory
if (err != 0)
  error ("failed to readdir (error code %d): %s", msg);
endif
logbook_indices = find (cellfun (@any, regexpi (files, 'logbook'));
logbook_filenames = files(logbook_indices);
```

A much less standard approach could be:

```
glob ('*[lL][oO][gG][bB][oO][kK]*')
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. In some cases, there were some lingering temporary files, which had "logbook' int he file name (but were invisible in windows) and which I had to discard (I used the `$` character that was part of the file name.